# Less CSS Compile order

Tags: css, less

I have a number of multiple LESS files which I want to compile using the WinLess compiler.

Now some of these files have dependencies of variables/mixins defined in separate less files.

My question is can I select all of these at once and compile using WinLess OR there has to be a sequence of compiling.

I am asking this question as I am getting NameError (e.g. transition is undefined) on compiling files which refer mixins, and actually even if I compile the var/mixin files first, I still get the NameError

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say you have dependencies in separate files. This means they should be `@import`ed, not compiled separately.
For example:

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

body {
  .my-mixin(@color);
}
```

Such code must produce only one file, as variables and mixins shouldn't produce any code.